# Concatenate dataframes giving importance to duplicates rows from a particular dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes.

```
    ID  D   F   G   Q
0   T1  1   3   4   5
1   T2  2   3   2   6
2   T3  4   7   7   8
3   T4  5   6   7   8
4   T5  6   9   0   9
```

```
    ID  Q   F   G   D
0   T10 10  54  44  55
1   T12 20  45  43  55
2   T11 30  45  65  55
3   T4  12  43  65  78
4   T5  42  45  87  90
```

I want to concatenate those. But I want T4 and T5 (which are present in both dataframe) values to be according to the first dataframe.
The orders of the columns are also not the same for the dataframes.
The final dataframe that I want looks like below.

```
    ID  D   F   G   Q
0   T1  1   3   4   5
1   T2  2   3   2   6
2   T3  4   7   7   8
3   T4  5   6   7   8
4   T5  6   9   0   9
0   T10 55  54  44  10
1   T12 55  45  43  20
2   T11 55  45  65  30
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat + drop_duplicates on `ID` col:

```
pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).drop_duplicates('ID') #.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
    ID   D   F   G   Q
0   T1   1   3   4   5
1   T2   2   3   2   6
2   T3   4   7   7   8
3   T4   5   6   7   8
4   T5   6   9   0   9
0  T10  55  54  44  10
1  T12  55  45  43  20
2  T11  55  45  65  30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.concat`function after filtering from your second dataframe the rows where ID appears also on the first dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['T1','T2','T3','T4','T5'],
                    'D':[1,2,4,5,6],
                    'F': [3,3,7,6,9],
                    'G': [4,2,7,7,0],
                    'Q': [5,6,8,8,9]})
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['T10','T12','T11','T4','T5'],
                    'Q':[10,20,30,12,42],
                    'F': [54,45,45,43,45],
                    'G': [44,43,65,65,87],
                    'D': [55,55,55,78,90]})
# remove from DF2 all rows where ID is also in DF1.ID
DF2_filtered = DF2.loc[~(DF2['ID'].isin(DF1['ID']))]
# concatenate those two dataframes
pd.concat([DF1,DF2_filtered])

#   D   F   G   ID  Q
#0  1   3   4   T1  5
#1  2   3   2   T2  6
#2  4   7   7   T3  8
#3  5   6   7   T4  8
#4  6   9   0   T5  9
#0  55  54  44  T10 10
#1  55  45  43  T12 20
#2  55  45  65  T11 30
```